# Arrayed Formula Not Working, how to get to work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to create the following array formula `=INDEX(Trips!F:F,MATCH(0,(Sheet1!C11=Trips!C:C)*(Sheet1!D11=Trips!J:J),0))` I hold down CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER but it inserts it with a ' before hand and not allowing the Formula to work.

Any suggestions on how to get around this, I've been googling for a good 35 minutes but no solutions have resolved it.

Comment: Usually with this type of formula `...MATCH(1,...` is used. You need to format the cell to e.g.  `General`, not `Text` and you need to hold down `Ctrl+Shift` and then press `Enter`.

Comment: As @VBasic2008 Sir, mentioned you need to use 1 instead of 0 in the LookupValue of Match Function since the lookup array which you have created within Match Function it returns an array of 1 and 0 this is because its performs math operation of Boolean Logic -True's and False's, here you can find more detailed info on the same, [Boolean_Logic_With_Match_Function](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Cheers!

Turns out some desk jockey thought he would format the cells to be a TEXT instead of General. Didn't even think of it until you mentioned it!